# Service ADSync was not found on computer

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, windows-server-2012, office365connectors

﻿Hello, for some time we have a problem while trying to run ADConnect on our Server 2012 R2. On title screen there is an error saying that "Service ADSync was not found on this computer." It is true. In Services there really is no service with this name. We recently upgraded from AADSync. Second service that broke down about the same time was Forefront Identity Manager 2010. Is it possible, that these two services are linked? Does anyone know how to fix these?

Answer (score 4):

If these keys exist, remove them.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\7EC08CB7BBBDF1045B31147D9AC698FB
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\E2D094C21044C254D9583B64140ED511

Comment: I had this same issue. For me, the long IDs {7EC089...} were different, but I looked through the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\ and found two entries with names that indicated they were Azure sync client tools. I removed those two keys and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Step through all the Keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\` and look for one with Product Name `Microsoft Azure AD Connect`.

Delete this and restart the installer.